# mysql select query skipping first row values

Tags: c#, mysql

There is only a drop down list with student ID and a grid view with students' images in my web page.
If I select a student Grid View has to show all the images of the selected student.
Problem is when I select a student my grid view is skipping first two values.
I mean if there are 6 images grid view shows only 4 images.
Here is my code:

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM images where Image_ID in (" + String.Join(",", getImage_ID()) + ")", con);
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    gvImages.DataSource = dt;
    gvImages.DataBind();
}
private List<int> getImage_ID()
{
    List<int> i = new List<int>();
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    string query = "Select Come_Image_ID1, Leave_Image_ID from register where Students_ID='" + getStudents_ID() + "' AND Come_Image_ID IS NOT NULL AND Leave_Image_ID IS NOT NULL"; 
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        foreach (DbDataRecord s in reader)
        {
            i.Add(s.GetInt32(0));
            i.Add(s.GetInt32(1));
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    return i;
}
```

What is the best coding practice for this issue?

Comment: I don't use Java, so this is just a guess: get rid of the `while` loop. The `foreach` is already looping over all the rows. `reader.Read()` is fetching the first row, so the `foreach` loop is starting with the next row.

Comment: That would explain why it skips the first row, I'm not sure why it skips the second.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing ways to read data. Either you a `while` loop:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    i.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
    i.Add(reader.GetInt32(1));
}
```

Or a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (DbDataRecord s in reader)
{
    i.Add(s.GetInt32(0));
    i.Add(s.GetInt32(1));
}
```

But not both.
Both the `while` and the `foreach` consume records from the cursor, and when you mix them like this you skip the records the `while` loop consumes.